# How can I play mp4 and avi files in a Movie Player?

Tags: software-recommendation, codecs, totem

I have installed Ubuntu on my emachines. It works well, so far, although I am unable to play movie files which I have saved from my old Windows installation.

I am using the default movie player that comes with the Ubuntu. I have seen other movie players in the Software Centre.

Should I install a new movie player (if so, which) or can I get the default movie player to play these files?

Answer (score 2):

[VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) - available from the Software Centre!

[image: VLC in Software Centre]

Answer (score 2):

In order to watch videos or play audio files you need the appropriate codec to decode these files. Some of them are non-free and are therefore not included in a standard Ubuntu installation.

Non-free codecs are provided by the package [libavcodec-extra-52](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libavcodec-extra-52) 
 that you will be able to install after adding [multiverse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) to your sources:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-52
```

After doing so all players that are based on ffmpeg are able to play audio or video files encoded with one of the supported codecs. This also includes players that come with a standard Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Xine or XBMC. Install all gStreamer plugins good/bad ugly set etc. OPen synaptic and search using "gstreamer" find all packages and install them(not the dbg and docs).

Answer (score 0):

if you are willing to try a new media player I recommend vlc (`sudo apt-get install vlc` from terminal) and is often on the front page of the software centre if you don't like vlc you could use UMplayer,Xine or XBMC (great for home theater) other methods are covered in other answers